# How to convert a Spring Application to a Spring Web Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Core Application which I would like to convert to a web project. I have already implemented all the business logic for my application in a normal Java Project using Eclipse IDE with Maven build.

But since I started out with a Core Java Project I do not have the WebContent folder or the Apache Tomcat wrapper. So what would be the best way to convert this project? Should I just change the pom.xml or does Spring have an alternative solution using the SpringBoot which I have already included in the pom.xml? (As you can tell I am new to Spring framework)

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the directories required for Web under `project facets`. You can do that by,

> Right click on the project properties. Select “Project Facets“, and
>   click “convert to faceted form…”

A nice tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-project-to-web-project-in-eclipse/) by mkyong have a look at it

Comment: But that would not reflect the changes I made to the pom.xml would it? And what if someone else pulls my project from git?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your `pom.xml` to enusre your changes made in it . You have to do `maven--install` for the project and check your libraries folder for newly added jars